# python lxml: case insensitive xpath tag name matching

Tags: python, xpath, case, lxml, case-insensitive

I'm using python + lxml to parse a spss file.

There seems to be many threads on this topic but the answers don't particular help me.

The answers I have come across:

```
- lower-case the entire input before parsing; 
- if you know the complete list of tags in advance
```

For me these suggestion would take too much time.

Instead I would like to match strings only when necessary.

Here is the line of code I would like to edit:

```
xpath("//definition//variable[@name='"+tag_name+"']")
```

How can I get a hit if tag_name is:

```
tag_name = "Q1top"
tag_name = "q1Top"
tag_name = "q1TOP"
etc
```

I'm guessing some form of regex would be in order???

Comment: Your question is confusing because "tag name" in XML usually means an element name, but what you are matching appears to be the value of a attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, you can incorporate regex from `http://exslt.org/regular-expressions` namespace in the XPath, for example :

```
ns = {"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"}
query = "//definition//variable[re:test(@name, '^{0}$', 'i')]".format(tag_name)
result = tree.xpath(query, namespaces=ns)
```

Comment: re:test? havnt seen that before, thought it wouldve been re:match

Comment: @Boosted_d16 See the documentation to compare : [`re:test`](http://exslt.org/regexp/functions/test/), [`re:match`](http://exslt.org/regexp/functions/match/). Both works as far as my simple test concerns

Answer (score 1):

Using [`local-name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name), [`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/translate) XPath functions:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> 
>>> root = lxml.etree.fromstring('''
... <root>
...     <parent>
...         <Q1top>1</Q1top>
...         <q1Top>2</q1Top>
...         <q1TOP>3</q1TOP>
...     </parent>
... </root>
... ''')
>>> root.xpath('.//*[translate(local-name(), '
...            '"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", '
...            '"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")="q1top"]')
[<Element Q1top at 0x7fd663354a28>,
 <Element q1Top at 0x7fd663354830>,
 <Element q1TOP at 0x7fd6633549e0>]
```

**UPDATE**

```
>>> root.xpath('.//*[translate(local-name(), '
...            '"QTOP", '
...            '"qtop")="q1top"]')
[<Element Q1top at 0x7fd663354a28>,
 <Element q1Top at 0x7fd663354830>,
 <Element q1TOP at 0x7fd6633549e0>]
```

Comment: Why not `translate(local-name(),"QTOP","qtop")="q1top" ?`

Comment: @splash58, Ah, nice suggestion. BTW, using `abcde....` will be more general. I updated the answer according to you.

Comment: OK I just asked out of curiosity :)